# Background not applying for parent element of position fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying a simple sticky header with position fixed property.The problem i encountered is, background css property is not applying for the parent element of the fixed div? what wrong i am doing here?

here is the code:

html:

```
  <div class="sticky_bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sticky">

         <div class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
         </div>

 <div class="menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Our Objectives</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
   <style>
   body{min-height:5000px;}
   .container{max-width:1170px;margin:0 auto;}
   header{width:100%;float:left;background:url("images/boat-bg.jpg")no-repeat center;background-size:cover;height:560px;}

 .sticky_bg{width:100%;float:left;background:#000;position:absolute;}
 .sticky {
     background: #444;
     position:fixed;
     width: 1170px;
     height: 80px;
     transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
     z-index:100;
   }

   .default {top: 0;}
   .fixed {top: -80px;}
  .logo{float:left;margin:25px 0 25px 1%;}
  .menu{float:right;margin:25px 1% 25px 0;}
  .menu ul li{list-style:none;float:left;}
  .menu ul li a{color:#fff; font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';padding:0 15px;border-right:1px solid #fff;}
  .menu ul li:last-child {margin-right:0;}
  .menu ul li:last-child a{border-right:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function($) {

     var ost = 0;

     $(window).scroll(function() {
        var cOst = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(cOst > ost) {
           $('.sticky').addClass('fixed').removeClass('default');
        }
     else {
          $('.sticky').addClass('default').removeClass('fixed');
         }

     ost = cOst;
     });

  })(jQuery);

 </script>
```

You can see a sticky feature once you scroll up, but the thing is only sticky css is applying, but i want "stickybg" element having background property should also move with sticky menu when you scroll up? how to do it?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/szvhapa5)

Comment: where is the demo?

Comment: **[Something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yr2a4x08/1/)**

Comment: no..please add the jquery library and check once. I dont know to add in fiddle

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for your code, what do you want to change exactly?   https://jsfiddle.net/szvhapa5/

Comment: yeah..u can notice,i want the parent div "stickybg" having background property to move along with "sticky" div,but how?

Comment: sticky is inside container,and stickybg is outside container with width 100% and background property,how would you get the same effect with stickybg moving along sticky div? hope its clear now!

Comment: But sticky_bg doesn't have any content besides the contariner with sticky class. So it doesn't make sense to try to color it? Or do you want to change the color of the navigation menu as @GuruprasadRao showed ?

Answer (score 0):

You need header to be fixed always.

```
 .sticky_bg{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#000;
     position:fixed;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szvhapa5/1/